# Run Airflow tasks in a loop until completion

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, airflow, etl

I'm building a basic ETL pipeline that hits a main endpoint which holds a list of IDs (variable amounts on each call) for processing. My current thinking is to use RabbitMQ as a queue system and have three tasks (Extract, Transform, Load) consume from RabbitMQ. Most tutorials I've seen online showcase a simple sequential execution of tasks before they exit. I've tried to construct a DAG that does this sequential action on each ID we receive. But I've run into problems trying to figure out how to schedule all these tasks through airflow, when I don't know how many IDs exist.

This is the general Tree view of the DAG in question:

[image: ETL Tree View]

I've begun the process of utilizing RabbitMQ to push these IDs to a queue and have celery spool up a variable amount of workers to handle the load. The problem I've run into is I don't know how to break out of the "consumption" loop. For example (I'm using pseudocode for some abstraction over RabbitMQ):

```py
def extract():
    # callback function when messages are sent to this worker
    def _extract(channel, url, rest):
        resp = request.get(url)
        channel.publish('transform_queue', resp)

    # attach the callback to the queue
    channel.basic_consume('extract_queue', callback=_extract)
    channel.start_consuming() # runs a pseudo loop waiting for messages here
```

Just as a note, some the variables (such as the channel underneath `_extract` are implicit, but will most likely be wrapped in a Custom Operator.

The Load and Transform functions work similarly. The problem I've run into is when the function starts consuming it doesn't stop until it's shutdown. I've been able to send sentinel messages to allow the function to "exit", however this will cause the Task to be marked as Failed, and sent to retry. For example here's the code for the sentinel shutdown.

```py
def extract():
    # callback function when messages are sent to this worker
    def _extract(channel, message, rest):
        if message == SHUTDOWN:
            exit()
        
        resp = requests.get(message.url)
        channel.publish('transform_queue', resp)

    # attach the callback to the queue
    channel.basic_consume('extract_queue', callback=_extract)
    channel.start_consuming() # runs a pseudo loop waiting for messages here
```

There's also the option to selectively cancel consumers, however this would just add more complexity as there is still the issue of polling for cancellation, and then that task would end up with the same issue above.

The main questions I have are:

Is there a way to exit with success in this setup?

Is this the best way to approach this problem? I imagine this is a common use case for airflow, so there must be some best practices or common setups. However, I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I could understand the following from your question and hence suggestions to explore the below.

> You are not sure of number of inputs and hence number of times you want to run the flow

You can create a custom operator (say FindIDs) which starts with finding out how many IDs you need to execute for and pushes the values to XComs. These messages can then be used for your other functions (say extractor, transformer and loader) and they can be set in a sequence as below

```
start >> findIds >> extractor >> transformer >> loader >> end
```

Check https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html?#xcoms

> You need to skip certain executions in case there are no inputs (or IDs in your case

I would use ShortCircuitOperator in this case and conditionally skip the execution for the DAG.
Check: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_short_circuit_operator.py

Comment: I'm aware of XCom's however, I don't think it's what I'm looking for in this case.